# How to programmatically edit iPhone accessibility settings during unit test?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

My application supports dynamic fonts. When user changes font size in settings (`Settings > General > Accessibility > Larger Text`) and jump back to application then every label should be updated.

It is implemented by overriding UILabel's function

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    guard previousTraitCollection?.preferredContentSizeCategory != traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory else { return }

    let metrics: UIFontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(
        forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body
    )
    font = metrics.scaledFont(for: font)
}
```

Now I need to test if other views react correctly to label's dynamic nature.

Specifically, I would like to have following unit test:

1. Create view with label
2. Get size of view
3. Change system font to bigger
4. Get size of view
5. Compare if sizes changed

```
func testDynamicFont() {

    let v: MyView = MyView()
    let oldSize: CGSize = v.intrinsicContentSize
    ??? What to do here? ???
    let newSize: CGSize = v.intrinsicContentSize
    XCTAssertNotEqual(
        oldSize, 
        newSize, 
        "Size of view should adjust to new environment"
    )
}
```

Comment: Does the below answer solves your problem?

Comment: Yes it do. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the System Font size using below code.

```
    let settings = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preferences")
    settings.launch()
    settings.tables.staticTexts["General"].tap()
    settings.tables.staticTexts["Accessibility"].tap()
    settings.tables.staticTexts["Larger Text"].tap()
    settings.sliders.element.adjust(toNormalizedSliderPosition: 0.7) // Increase as you need
```

To go back to your own app,

```
let yourapp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.xxx.yourappbundleid")
yourapp.activate()
```

Tested in iPhone (Real Device), iOS 12.1.4